# Retrieving DLL Metadata from VBScript?

Tags: dll, scripting, vbscript, wsh

Using only VBScript (launched from Windows Scripting Host) can I pull the DLL metadata from kernel32.dll?  Specifically, I'm looking for the version info and the architecture specified in the DLL header.  Can this be done without any dependencies?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're just looking for the version, you can use the [`FileSystemObject`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b4e05k97.aspx).

If you're looking for other thing pieces of info besides FileVersion, there's some pre-written code [here](http://www.jsware.net/jsware/scripts.php5#fvinfo).

Comment: Oh, thank you for the link to GetFileVersion, that's a good start.

Comment: The first link is broken - clicking goes to second link's target.